# Software Custom Updater, Signed Apk install PARSE ERROR

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-file, start-activity

I'm creating application custom updater, got Parse error while updating.

I download signed apk using AsyncTask

```
output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir()+"/update.apk");
```

Download completes succesfully, then I try to run apk like this:

```
File file = new File("file://"+context.getFilesDir(), "update.apk");
file.setReadable(true, false);
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(promptInstall);
```

App starts to update, but then gomes my issue,

```
Parse Error: An error occurred while parsing the package
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable app instalation from unknown sources?

Comment: Yes, I have application already installed and just trying to make custom updater

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND SOLUTION..

I forgot to add permission to read from external storage, added this line into

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**AsyncTask**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground (String...sUrl){
    ......
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File outputFile = new File(sd, "/download/update.apk");
    output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    ......
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ......
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File inputFile = new File(sd, "/download/update.apk");

    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(inputFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(promptInstall);
    ......
}
```